# RegexReplace different output according to compiler

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

[LIVE](https://www.onlinegdb.com/1wtJkKeMj)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string text = R"(11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111
11111111111110000000
11111111111000000000
11111111100011111100
11111111100111100000)";

    std::regex re("^1+\n");
    std::string str = std::regex_replace(text, re, "");
    std::cout << str;
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the exact same code when compiled under visual studio, trims ***all*** lines containing `11111111111111111111`?

I would like to it behave the same as on the link above, replacing just the first occurrence.

Do i need any kind of 'special' flag into the regex?

Comment: In MSVC, the `^` anchor matches start of any line, not just the start of a string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how do i 'tell' it to match just the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my answer. It might be a compiler difference. You can refer to the [flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/regex-functions?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(std%253A%253Aregex_replace)%3Bk(regex_replace)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue#regex_replace) and  similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603396/regex-replace-gives-different-output-according-to-compiler).

```
std::regex_constants::match_flag_type fonly =
    std::regex_constants::format_first_only;
std::regex re("^1+\n");
std::string str = std::regex_replace(text, re, "", fonly);
```

Comment: When should i use this flag?

Comment: So can i assume that this flag set `regex_replace` to replace only the `first` occurence?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105581/stdregex-replace-only-first-occurence

Comment: To begin, why does the regex match things in multiple lines? By default std::regex lib matches things multi-line?

Comment: [MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/regex-constants-class?view=msvc-170#match_flag_type)`format_first_only -- do not search for matches after the first one.` . Looks like  regex matches multiple lines by default.

Comment: E.g. The description of the document `regex_match`:
Tests whether a regular expression matches the **entire target string**.